# how to recode (and reverse code) variables in columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am picking up R again after last using it in 2013. I am getting used to using dplyr, but I am running into a problem with a simple task.
I  have a table that looks like

```
Participant Q1       Q2      Q3     Q4       Q5
1           agree  neutral   NA    Disagree  Agree
2           neutral agree    NA     NA       NA
```

My goal

```
   Participant Q1       Q2      Q3     Q4       Q5
    1           3       2       NA      1       3
    2           2       1       NA     NA       NA
```

I want to be able to change the categorical value to a numerical value for columns Q1:Q5, but all the examples that I see of using recode for dplyr work for rows and no columns. (I might be missing something in the examples). I then want to be able to pick column Q1 and Q2 and reverse code it.

I am trying to learn to do this in dplyr if possible

Thanks

Comment: Data frames are built for column operations. I would say that you should `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather` your data into a long format and then proceed as is usually done, with variables in commons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure what you mean with variable sin commons. I did as you suggested 'gather (table, "Question", "Answer", 2:6)' and I can now use the recode to replace the values for me Answer colum but then they are placed in the values and not in the table

Comment: I mean *columns*, not commons.

Comment: Agreed about your data not being tidy and therefore dplyr is not recommended until you use tidyr::gather .


I arrived at this page because I was looking up the new dplyr::recode() function, which might be helpful once you get the data into tidy format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in `base R` without using any package.  Create a lookup named vector ('v1'), loop over the columns and use that vector to change the values in the columns

```
v1 <- setNames(c(1:3, 3), c("Disagree", "neutral", "agree", "Agree"))
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) if(any(!is.na(x))) v1[x] else NA)
df1 
#  Participant Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5
#1           1  3  2 NA  1  3
#2           2  2  3 NA NA NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Participant = 1:2, Q1 = c("agree", "neutral"), 
Q2 = c("neutral", "agree"), Q3 = c(NA, NA), Q4 = c("Disagree", 
NA), Q5 = c("Agree", NA)), .Names = c("Participant", "Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: This is so much better. Still figuring out how all the parts works, but this takes care of the reverse code part also. Thanks so much

Comment: oops- agreed this should not have been downvoted based on the StackOverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 11):

This is fairly straightforward now thanks to dplyr's `recode` function. Here's one way to do it:

```
# Generate a dataframe to match yours

df <- data.frame(
  participant = c(1,2),
  Q1 = c("agree", "neutral"),
  Q2 = c("neutral", "agree"),
  Q3 = c(NA,NA),
  Q4 = c("Disagree", NA),
  Q5 = c("Agree", NA)
)

# Use recode to recode the data

df_recode <- df %>%
  mutate(Q1 = recode(Q1, "agree" = 3, "neutral" = 2),
         Q2 = recode(Q2, "neutral" = 2, "agree" = 1),
         Q4 = recode(Q4, "Disagree" = 1),
         Q5 = recode(Q5, "Agree" = 3)
  )
```

You'll also want to read about the `.default` and `.missing` arguments in the help file to be sure you aren't introducing `NAs` when you don't mean to.