# Recode and Mutate_all in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use recode and mutate_all to recode columns. However, for some reason, I am getting an error. I do believe this post is similar to [how to recode (and reverse code) variables in columns with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088328/how-to-recode-and-reverse-code-variables-in-columns-with-dplyr) but the answer in that post has used lapply function.

Here's what I tried after reading dplyr package's help pdf.

```
by_species<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)
tbl_species<-as_data_frame(by_species)
tbl_species %>% mutate_all(funs(. * 0.4))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     V1    V2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   0.4   1.2
2   0.8   1.6
```

So, this works well.

However, this doesn't work:

```
grades<-matrix(c("A","A-","B","C","D","B-","C","C","F"),3,3)
tbl_grades <- as_data_frame(grades)
tbl_grades %>% mutate_all(funs(dplyr::recode(.,A = '4.0')))
```

I get this error:

```
    Error in vapply(dots[missing_names], function(x) make_name(x$expr), character(1)) : 
values must be length 1,
but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 3
```

Can someone please explain what's the problem and why above code isn't working?

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get an error when I do `tbl_grades %>% mutate_all(funs(recode(., A = '4.0')))`, though I'm not sure why that works, but `dplyr::recode` doesn't.

Comment: The problem appears to be with `funs()`. It calls an internal function `make_name` to make a pretty name for the column but it seems to get confused by the `::` function. That's why `funs(recode(.,A = '4.0')` works but `funs(dplyr::recode(.,A = '4.0')` does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Mir has done a good job describing the problem. Here's one possible workaround. Since the problem is in generating the name, you can supply your own name

```
tbl_grades %>% mutate_all(funs(recode=recode(.,A = '4.0')))
```

Now this does add columns rather than replace them. Here's a function that will "forget" that you supplied those names

```
dropnames<-function(x) {if(is(x,"lazy_dots")) {attr(x,"has_names")<-FALSE}; x}
tbl_grades %>% mutate_all(dropnames(funs(recode=dplyr::recode(.,A = '4.0'))))
```

This should behave like the original. Although really

```
tbl_grades %>% mutate_all(dropnames(funs(recode(.,A = '4.0'))))
```

because dplyr often has special c++ versions of some functions that it can use if it recognized the functions (like `lag` for example) but this will not happen if you also specify the namespace (if you use `dplyr::lag`).

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. This did work, but I am curious--what would you do if there is a function conflict? For instance, I have dplyr::recode and car::recode function. I'd appreciate your thoughts. Is writing dropnames() function the only option? (As mentioned in my response to Mir, I get an error if I don't use namespace indicator "::")...

Comment: As far as I can tell. I would create an issue on the dplyr GitHub to see if it can be fixed or has a better workaround.

Comment: I've posted the issue: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2057 This is for those who might be interested in updates...

Comment: @Tower_Watch Can you change the title of that issue? Something more descriptive like "funs()" errors with namespaced function"

Answer (score 4):

If we call it without the `dplyr::` then it works fine.

```
funs(recode(., A = '4.0'))
<fun_calls>
$ recode: recode(., A = "4.0")

tbl_grades %>% mutate_all(funs(recode(. ,A = '4.0')))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1   4.0     C     C
2    A-     D     C
3     B    B-     F
```

The issue lies in the `funs` call. If we extract that part out the same error appears.

```
funs(dplyr::recode(., A = '4.0'))

Error in vapply(dots[missing_names], function(x) make_name(x$expr), character(1)) : 
values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 3
```

The issue boils down to the fact that `::` is a function itself. (see `` ?`::` ``). To visualize this a little better, we look at both the infix and prefix ways of writing the function.

```
`::`(dplyr, recode)
function (.x, ..., .default = NULL, .missing = NULL) 
{
    UseMethod("recode")
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>

dplyr::recode
function (.x, ..., .default = NULL, .missing = NULL) 
{
UseMethod("recode")
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

`funs` attempts to extract the function names of its arguments by grabbing the first element of the call object and calling `as.character` on it. The first element of the call object is the calling function and subsequent elements are the argument values. For example:

```
as.call(quote(recall(., A = '4.0')))
recall(., A = "4.0")

as.call(quote(recall(., A = '4.0')))[[1]]
recall

as.call(quote(recall(., A = '4.0')))[[2]]
.

as.call(quote(recall(., A = '4.0')))[[3]]
"4.0"

as.call(quote(recall(., A = '4.0')))[[4]]
Error in as.call(quote(recall(., A = "4.0")))[[4]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

This runs into issues when `dplyr::recode` is used because this creates a nested call object. When we grab the first element, we get not just a name of a function, but an entire function call.

```
as.call(quote(dplyr::recall(., A = '4.0')))
dplyr::recall(., A = "4.0")

as.call(quote(dplyr::recall(., A = '4.0')))[[1]]
dplyr::recall

as.call(quote(dplyr::recall(., A = '4.0')))[[1]][[1]]
`::`

as.call(quote(dplyr::recall(., A = '4.0')))[[1]][[2]]
dplyr

as.call(quote(dplyr::recall(., A = '4.0')))[[1]][[3]]
recall
```

In contrast to when `recode` is called without `dplyr::`.

```
as.call(quote(recall(., A = '4.0')))[[1]][[1]]
Error in as.call(quote(recall(., A = "4.0")))[[1]][[1]] : 
  object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

Because the first element when `dplyr::` is included is a whole function call, `as.character` results in a vector that has both the name of a function and its arguments.

```
as.call(quote(dplyr::recall(., A = '4.0')))[[1]] %>% as.character()
[1] "::"     "dplyr"  "recall"
```

`Funs` reasonably expects the name of the function to have only one element, not three, and thus errors out.

Comment: Thanks Mir. Your comment is insightful, but when I run tbl_grades %>% mutate_all(funs(recode(.,A = '4.0'))), I get an error "Error: unused argument (A = "4.0")" R has a conflict between car::recode and dplyr::recode. How do I resolve this? I added "dplyr::" to resolve this conflict. I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: If you aren't using the `car` version of recode, you could load the `dplyr` package after the `car` one. That way `recode` will default to the `dplyr` version. You can first restart the R session and then load the packages in again, or you can detach the packages using `detach("package:car", unload=TRUE)` and `detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE)`.