# How to use mutate_all and recode together properly using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have been trying to use the dplyr variant of recode, combined with mutate_all on all variables in a dataset, but it does not yield the expected output. Other answers that I found does not address this problem (e.g. [Recode and Mutate_all in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809509/recode-and-mutate-all-in-dplyr))

Here is what I tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(car)

# Create sample data
df <- data_frame(a = c("Yes","Maybe","No","Yes"), b = c("No","Maybe","Yes","Yes"))

# Using dplyr::recode
df %>% mutate_all(funs(recode(., `1` = "Yes", `0` = "No", `NA` = "Maybe")))
```

No effect on values:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
      a     b
  <chr> <chr>
1   Yes    No
2 Maybe Maybe
3    No   Yes
4   Yes   Yes
```

What I want can be reproduced using car::Recode:

```
# Using car::Recode
df %>% mutate_all(funs(Recode(., "'Yes' = 1; 'No' = 0; 'Maybe' = NA")))
```

This is the desired outcome:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0
2    NA    NA
3     0     1
4     1     1
```

Comment: This can be done without using `recode` too

Comment: I know it can be done, but I would like to know what am I missing with dplyr::recode. I would like to avoid ifelse-like solutions.

Comment: Not the answer, but a simple alternative: `df[] <- factor(unlist(df), levels = c("Yes", "No", "Maybe"), labels = c(1, 0, NA))`

Comment: It seems to work inside `mutate` i.e. `df %>% mutate(a = dplyr::recode(a, Yes = 1, No = 2, Maybe = NA_real_))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1    No
2    NA Maybe
3     2   Yes
4     1   Yes`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You inverted the 'key/values' in `dplyr::recode`. This works for me:

```
df %>% mutate_all(funs(recode(., Yes = 1L, No = 0L, Maybe = NA_integer_)))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0
2    NA    NA
3     0     1
4     1     1
```

Note that it throws an error if you don't specify the type of `NA`.

Also you can use quoted or unquoted value (e.g.: Both `Yes` or `'Yes'` work)

Comment: right, and you don't even need to quote the Yes, No etc

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. I was somehow confused by the documentation examples, but I guess it is my bad!

Comment: Warning message:
`funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.